# Record changes pend approval by a privileged user; Its like versioning combined with approvals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a requirement that certain attribute changes to records are not reflected in the user interface until those changes are approved. Further, if a change is made to an `approved` record, the user will be presented with the record as it exists before `approval`.

**My first try...**

was to go to a versioning plugin such as `paper_trail`, `acts_as_audited`, etc. and add an `approved` attribute to their version model. Doing so would not only give me the ability to 'rollback' through versions of the record, but also SHOULD allow me to differentiate between whether a version has been approved or not.

I have been working down this train of thought for awhile now, and the problem I keep running into is on the user side. That is, how do I query for a collection of `approved` records? I *could* (and tried) writing some helper methods that get a collection of records, and then loop over them to find an "approved" version of the record. My primary gripe with this is how quickly the number of database hits can grow. My next attempt was to do something as follows:

```
Version.
  where(:item_type => MyModel.name, :approved => true).
  group(:item_type).collect do |v|

  # like the 'reify' method of paper_trail
  v.some_method_that_converts_the_version_to_a_record 
end
```

So assuming that the `some_method...` call doesn't hit the database, we kind of end up with the data we're interested in. The main problem I ran into with this method is I can't use this "finder" as a scope. That is, I can't append additional scopes to this lookup to narrow my results further. For example, my records may also have a `cool` scope that only shows records where `:cool => true`. Ideally, I would want to look up my records as `MyModel.approved.cool`, but here I guess I would have to get my collection of approved models and then loop over them for `cool` ones would would result in the very least in having a bunch of records initialized in memory for no reason.

**My next try...**

involved creating a special type of "pending record" that basically help "potential" changes to a record. So on the user end you would lookup whatever you wanted as you normally would. Whenever a pending record is `apply!`(ed) it would simply makes those changes to the actual record, and alls well... *Except* about 30 minutes into it I realize that it all breaks down if an "admin" wishes to go back and contribute more to his change before approving it. I guess my only option would be either to:

1. Force the admin to approve all changes before making additional ones (that won't go over well... nor should it).
2. Try to read the changes out of the "pending record" model and apply them to the existing record without saving. Something about this idea just doesn't quite sound "right".

I would ***love*** someone's input on this issue. I have been wrestling with it for some time, and I just can't seem to find the way that feels right. I like to live by the "if its hard to get your head around it, you're probably doing it wrong" mantra.

And this is kicking my tail...

Answer (score 5):

How about, create an association:

```
class MyModel < AR::Base
  belongs_to :my_model
  has_one    :new_version, :class_name => MyModel

  # ...
end
```

When an edit is made, you basically clone the existing object to a new one. Associate the existing object and the new one, and set a `has_edits` attribute on the existing object, the `pending_approval` attribute on the new one.

How you treat the objects once the admin approves it depends on whether you have other associations that depend on the id of the original model.

In any case, you can reduce your queries to:

```
objects_pending_edits = MyModel.where("has_edits = true").all
```

then with any given one, you can access the new edits with `obj.new_version`. If you're really wanting to reduce database traffic, eager-load that association.

Comment: Steve, thanks for the input! I like the idea you've had. Its sort of a hybrid of *my next try*, but maybe there is still a problem. What would you do in the case of a ***new*** record that hasn't been approved? My instinct would be to have a `new?` flag on the record that is `true` by default and set to `false` once the first change has been applied. To me the problem would be an added layer of complication. Now you'd have to keep up with that flag on the "admin" side and after a record has been approved for creation, there is a useless column in your model :/

Comment: A new record that is not approved would not be approved and have `object.new_version.blank?` be true. Right? Although, you could write a helper for this. But the states are: unapproved&&no_new_version (new), approved, unapproved&&new_version, approved. These can be synthesized with the used of the data I proposed unless I'm missing something.

Comment: I gotcha now. I think I had overlooked the `has_edits` flag when I originally went through your post, and just assumed we would know that a record is pending approval if has an associated `new_version`. I think I'm on board with your logic. Your statement "How you treat the objects once the admin approves it depends on whether you have other associations that depend on the id of the original model." worries me a little bit however, it seems like unless treated very carefully, you could mess up some associations.. I guess that's why you should treat them carefully :P

Comment: Right. I don't know your problem domain, but regardless of what technology (acts_as_whatever) you use for this, you will probably wind up copying the attributes from the edited version to the original upon approval. A nice twist would be to swap the attributes such that the edited version becomes the "undo" version. Just a thought. It would seem this method of treating approval-only edits matches your desire to keep the database access to a minimum and you should be able to encapsulate the after-approval logic in the model and test it thoroughly. Yes?

Comment: Steve, thank you again so much for hanging in there with me. I'm going to take our discussion and step back from this to let it all sink in. Once I finally settle on an implementation (could be awhile), I'll be sure and post it up as a new 'answer' to this question. You have been an enormous help! I just love the Ruby community :)

Comment: Lamvery, I am tackling the same problem in my application. Can you please post your final implementation.